# Como simplificar javascript "getElementByid"

Tags: javascript

Queria saber se é possível simplificar esta instrução quando clicar ativar os imputs. Posso colocar input-smtpname, input-smtplogin.... etc...?

```
document.getElementById('customSwitch1').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('input-smtpname').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('input-smtplogin').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('input-smtp').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('input-smtpport').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('input-smtpass').disabled = !this.checked;
    document.getElementById('input-smtpssl').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Comment: Pode clarificar a questão pois não faz sentido. Você pede uma simplificação, ok, mas esse trecho **"...Posso colocar input-smtpname, input-smtplogin.... etc...?"** precisa ser esclarecido pois é ausente de significado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu até entendo sua necessidade, mas duas pessoas entenderam o que estava pensando em fazer, creio também que não preciso ser muito claro, pois como disse, pessoas entenderam e me ajudaram com meu objetivo!

Comment: Se as respostas o satisfizeram melhor, mas eu suspeito que o seu problema possa resolvido com uma única linha. Só não tenho informações para afirmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode definir um array com os ids dos elementos que devem ser afetados, e fazer um ciclo que faz o toggle por cada um deles, exemplo:

```
// Supondo que todos os elementos tenham "input-" como prefixo
const elementIds = ['smtpname', 'smtplogin', 'smtp', 'smtpport', 'smtpass', 'smtpssl'];

for(let el of elementIds){
  let id = `input-${el}`;
  let element = document.getElementById(id);

  element.disabled = !element.checked;
}
```

Você também pode definir uma função e passar os elementos que a mesma deve iterar como um array da seguinte maneira:

```
function toggleElements(...ids){
  for(let el of ids){
    let id = `input-${el}`;
    let element = document.getElementById(id);

    element.disabled = !element.checked;
  }
}
```

E então passar os elementos a serem atualizados para a mesma da seguinte forma:

```
toggleElements('smtpname', 'smtplogin', ...)
```

Comment: gostei da sua explicação, tanto é que tive uma ideia de usar em outro formulário. Maginifico!

Answer (score 0):

> Sim, pode colocar `input-*****` ou inp-****, alias vai facilitar a simplificação do código

`input[id^="input-"]` seleciona os inputs que possuem o `id` com um valor que começa exatamente com uma determinada string, no caso,  `input-` [veja aqui](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> Com apenas uma linha de código e jquery resolve seu problema

```js
document.getElementById('customSwitch1').onchange = function() {

 $('input[id^="input-"]').prop("disabled", !$('input[id^="input-"]').prop("disabled"));

       /* ############### bonus ############### */
       if($('#customSwitch1').prop("checked")){
         $("#label").text("Desabilitar");
       }else{
         $("#label").text("Habilitar");
       }
      /* ##################################### */

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="customSwitch1" name="check" value="true">
<label id="label" for="check">Habilitar</label><br>

  <input id="input-name" type="text" disabled>
  <input id="input-email" type="text" disabled>
  <input id="input-cpf" type="text" disabled>
  <input id="input-telefone" type="text" disabled>
  <input id="input-tantofaz" type="text" disabled>
```

Answer (score -1):

Veja se isso faz sentido pro seu caso.

Criamos uma pequena função que pega todos os `inputs` pelo `type`, e varre todos eles habilitando e desabilitando de acordo com o `checkbox`, desta maneira, não levamos em consideração os `ids`.

```js
const check = document.querySelector('#check');
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const inputs = form.querySelectorAll("input");

check.addEventListener('change', event => {
  if(event.target.checked === true) {
    habilitar(true)
  } else {
    habilitar(false)
  }
})


const habilitar = (value) => {
  inputs.forEach(input => {
    input.disabled = value;
  })
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" name="check" value="true">
<label for="check">Habilitar</label><br>
<form id="form">
  <input id="input-name" type="text">
  <input id="input-email" type="text">
  <input id="input-cpf" type="text">
  <input id="input-telefone" type="text">
  <input id="input-tantofaz" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: isso mesmo boa alternativa! Mas eu fico pensando, creio que vá afetar outros inputs do formulário! Creio que estou certo, por isso eu tenho que determinar os que preciso para evitar que desative indevidamente outros!

Answer (score -2):

Não existe atalho nativo, uma sugestão seria criar um alias para as funções `querySelector` e `querySelectorAll` assim como as ferramentas de debug dos navegadores fazem:

```
const $  = document.querySelector;
const $$ = document.querySelectorAll;
```

Dessa forma você poderia buscar os elementos da sua página com uma sintaxe similar ao jQuery:

```
$('#customSwitch1').onchange = function() {
    $('#input-smtpname').disabled = !this.checked;
    $('#input-smtplogin').disabled = !this.checked;
    $('#input-smtp').disabled = !this.checked;
    $('#input-smtpport').disabled = !this.checked;
    $('#input-smtpass').disabled = !this.checked;
    $('#input-smtpssl').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Ou

```
$('#customSwitch1').onchange = function() {
    const elementos = $$('#input-smtpname, #input-smtplogin, #input-smtp, #input-smtpport, #input-smtpass, #input-smtpssl');
    for (const e of elementos) e.disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Mas isso é uma solução subjetiva para algo que nem é um problema, que honestamente, nem sei se isso se encaixa no escopo site.

Comment: Magnifico User140828, gostei da segunda opção me passa de algo mais limpo, como não será rotina, apenas em dois formulário eu creio que será a mais apropriada!